# Cosmos always gets 404 when doing container.ReadItemAsync even though the item is there

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am pulling my hair out for this weird error. I have created an azure cosmosdb and manually inserted an item in the container and then query it from C# code:

```
        public async Task<T> ReadAsync<T>(string documentId, string collectionName, string partitionKey)
            where T : class
        {
            Requires.NotNullOrWhiteSpace(documentId, nameof(documentId));
            Requires.NotNullOrWhiteSpace(collectionName, nameof(collectionName));

            return await this.PerformActionAsync(
                $"ReadAsync {documentId}. Collection: {collectionName}.",
                async client =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Container container = client.GetDatabase(this.cosmosDbDatabaseName).GetContainer(collectionName);
                        ItemResponse<T> response = await container.ReadItemAsync<T>(id: documentId, partitionKey: new PartitionKey(partitionKey)).ConfigureAwait(true);
                        return response.Resource;
                    }
                    catch (CosmosException ex)
                    {
                        if (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                        {
                            resultStatus = NotFound;
                            return null;
                        }

                        resultStatus = Exception;
                        throw new Exception("The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.");
                    }
```

The code always returns **404 NotFound**! But I can see the item in the container from DataExplorer!

Can anyone shed some light on me? Much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the document from Cosmos DB and values you're using for document id and partition key?

Answer (score 2):

The reason was that I got confused by partitionKey, which should be the value of the partitionKey!

Comment: Don't feel bad - this tends to be a common mistake. I've answered a few similar questions here about this, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61730319/272109) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60149506/272109). I was going to refer you to those, in a comment under your question, and then saw you figured it out already.