# Unable to retrieve documents in Cosmos DB stored procedure

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to retrieve documents matching an id through a simple SQL query in my JavaScript stored procedure. But it always returns that no document matches the id found. Tried all the things available in the Microsoft Documentation and the other StackOverflow answers. Here is my function:

```js
function updateDocument () {
  let context = getContext();
  let collection = context.getCollection();
  let collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
  let response = context.getResponse();

  tryQueryAndUpdate();

  function tryQueryAndUpdate () {
    var filterQuery = 'select * from user r WHERE r.id = "f5eddf33-7826-40c3-a634-9c349e5c7f73"';

    let isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, filterQuery, {}, function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
      if (err) throw err;

      if (documents.length > 0) {
        console.log("Documents exists - " + documents.length);
      } else {
        // Else a document with the given id does not exist..
        console.log("Document doesn't exist " + documents.length);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

My document:

```json
{
    "firstName": "firstname",
    "lastName": "lastname",
    "email": "firstname.lastname@gmail.com",
    "businessRole": "",
    "functionalArea": null,
    "type": "internal",
    "status": "enable",
    "modifiedDate": "2020-07-10T14:34:54.557Z",
    "id": "f5eddf33-7826-40c3-a634-9c349e5c7f73",
    "_rid": "H+pKAKZdGd0BAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/H+pKAA==/colls/H+pKAKZdGd0=/docs/H+pKAKZdGd0BAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"730103dd-0000-0100-0000-5f6302800000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "securityGroup": "c5d3dc10-bfa0-11ea-8394-48463089baf6",
    "engagementId": "945acacf-a3ea-43ef-8e31-70576055ba4f",
    "sort": {
        "firstName": "firstname",
        "lastName": "lastname"
    },
    "userStatus": "active",
    "_ts": 1600324224
}
```

[document:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXD5X.png)
[container:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d90nD.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Execution parameters:

[image: Execution parameters]

Console output:

[image: Console output]

Comment: From your screenshot, you have a partition key of `/type`. Did you set a value for `type` in your call to your stored procedure? Please edit your question to show how you call your stored procedure.

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon, Yes, /type is included. I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: You have the wrong value in your partition key. You entered the *key* (`"/type"`). You need to enter the *value* that you're searching for. Cosmos DB already knows that `/type` is the field used for partition key. So, in your example, enter `"internal"` as your partition key value.

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon, Thank you so much. I had gotten it totally wrong. Appreciate your help

Comment: FYI - there are similar questions where people have run into the same issue (just in different contexts), where I've provided a formal answer. You can read two such answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61730319/272109) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60149506/272109).